# TypeError in subprocess command for youtube-dl

Tags: subprocess, typeerror, youtube-dl

I'm trying to write a very simple script which passes in a .csv file and runs youtube-dl (and specified args) for each link in the file- saving the files to a certain directory.

The format of the csv is Artist;Title;Link. And the script:

```
import pandas as pd
import subprocess

def get_music(csv):

df = pd.read_csv(csv, sep=";", skipinitialspace=True)

for _, row in df.iterrows():        
    subprocess.call(['youtube-dl', "x",
                    "--output ~/mydir/%(title)s.%(ext)s",
                    "--extract-audio", "--youtube-skip-dash-manifest",
                    "--prefer-ffmpeg", "--audio-format", "mp3"], row.Link)


get_music("CSV.csv")
```

When I run this however, I get the following error:

"raise TypeError("bufsize must be an integer")
TypeError: bufsize must be an integer"

I'm afraid I don't understand how the bufsize is getting passed something other than an integer. Simply put, what am I doing wrong, and how should I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, your second argument to `subprocess.call`, which specifies the bufsize, is `row.Link`, which seems to be the URL you want to download. Instead of `"x"`, pass in the actual link. Also, there is no option `"--output ~/mydir/%(title)s.%(ext)s"`, as option names do not contain spaces. Most likely, you want

```
subprocess.call(['youtube-dl', row.Link,
                 "--output", "~/mydir/%(title)s.%(ext)s",
                 "--extract-audio", "--youtube-skip-dash-manifest",
                 "--prefer-ffmpeg", "--audio-format", "mp3"])
```

Comment: Danke sehr Phillip! Much appreciated. That worked like a charm.